# How to show image randomly with fade-in fade-out using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

This is HTML Code.

```
<div id="Slogan">
<h1>
<img src="img1.gif" />
<img src="img2.gif" />
<img src="img3.gif" />
<img src="img4.gif" />
<img src="img5.gif" />
</h1>
</div>

#slogan {float:left;position:relative;width:100%;}
```

I want show all image randomly but one by one like slide show, with fade-in fade-out effect. How to do with jquery?

I need lightest possible way.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Define a random integer function
function random( n ){
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * n );
}

// Define some variables, hide all images and show just one of them.
var transition_time = 500;
var waiting_time = 500;
var images = $('div#Slogan img');
var n = images.length;
var current = random( n );
images.hide();
images.eq( current ).show();

// Periodically, we fadeOut the current image and fadeIn a random one
var interval_id = setInterval( function(){
    images.eq( current ).fadeOut( transition_time, function(){
        current = random( n );
        images.eq( current ).fadeIn( transition_time );
    } );
}, 2 * transition_time + waiting_time);

// You can then stop the effect with:
// clearInterval( interval_id );
```

Comment: Hey Erik, that's a great script. Do you know if there's a way to prevent the same image showing up twice in a row? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

So there's a really cool plugin that may (or may not, depending on how light you want it) do exactly what you want, it's called [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/), it has a load of different transitions but [on my website](http://motorsport.beneverard.co.uk) I choose to use the fade in fade out, it's very customisable

http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

Comment: plugin s heavy. can we make more simple?

Comment: I feared it might not be simple enough, never the less if you take a look at how they achieve the fading in and out, they basically set the background image of the container div then loop through each of the images showing and hiding (fade effect) in turn.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [jQuery Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)?